# flex containers wont alight properly

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to make a row with 3 elements, but the third one just won't fit I've tried: changing the `justify-content` I've tried adding a `flex:1` even tho in theory they should already have that. I've tried removing the margins beacaus I thought the flex containers may be too big to fit 3 of them in one row, but it didn't help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUsAY.png)

```
      <div id="myprojects">
    <div class="pr_cont">
      <a href="#"><img id="project_img" src="images/img04.png" alt=""></a>
      <div class="project_div">
        <p id="project_textA">Nascetur nunc varius commodo</p><br><br>
        <p id="project_textB">Interdum amet accumsan placerat commodo ut amet aliquam blandit nunc tempor lobortis nunc non. Mi accumsan.</p><br><br>
        <a href="#" id="more_box">View more</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="pr_cont">
      <a href="#"><img id="project_img" src="images/img04.png" alt=""></a>
      <div class="project_div">
        <p id="project_textA">Nascetur nunc varius commodo</p><br><br>
        <p id="project_textB">Interdum amet accumsan placerat commodo ut amet aliquam blandit nunc tempor lobortis nunc non. Mi accumsan.</p><br><br>
        <a href="#" id="more_box">View more</a>
      </div>

      <div class="pr_cont">
        <a href="#"><img id="project_img" src="images/img04.png" alt=""></a>
        <div class="project_div">
          <p id="project_textA">Nascetur nunc varius commodo</p><br><br>
          <p id="project_textB">Interdum amet accumsan placerat commodo ut amet aliquam blandit nunc tempor lobortis nunc non. Mi accumsan.</p><br><br>
          <a href="#" id="more_box">View more</a>
      </div>

  </div>
```

.

```
#myprojects {
display: flex;
justify-content:space-around;
width: 90%;
height: 50px;
margin: 0% 5% 0 5%;

}
.pr_cont {
margin: 0 5%;
width: 100%;
border-radius: 10px;
width: 400px; 
}
#project_img {
border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
}
.project_div {
background-color: #333;
height: 250px;
width: 400px;
border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}
#project_textA {
margin-top: -4px;
border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
color: white;
text-align:center;
padding-top: 30px;
font-size: 24px;
font-weight: 400;
}
#project_textB {
margin: 0;
font-size: 18px;
color: gray;
text-align: center;
}
#more_box {
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
color: white;
width: 10%;
margin: 0 5%;
background-color: #bd00ff;
padding: 20px 36%;
border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems an issue on your html, I am missing a `</div>` before the last item so it is being shown inside of the second one:

```
<div id="myprojects">
  <div class="pr_cont">
    ...
  </div>

 <div class="pr_cont">
   ...

 <div class="pr_cont">
   ... 
 </div>
</div>
```

So it should be like:

```
<div id="myprojects">
  <div class="pr_cont">
    ...
  </div>

 <div class="pr_cont">
   ...
 </div>

 <div class="pr_cont">
   ... 
 </div>
</div>
```